# C# timer that fires every X seconds, but stays in synch with real time (i.e. with no drift)

Tags: c#, .net, timer, drift

Is there a .NET Timer available in C# that can ensure there is no "drift" in between events? That is, if you set the timer to go off every X seconds, that after days of operating it won't drift, i.e. to ensure that approach number of X seconds events in a day remains in synch with what it should be?

If not, is there a well known code example that would wrap a Timer function in C# to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sorry for only giving you a link to [quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/), but this is a fully qualified, enterprise, tested, ... library ... you don't need to reinvent the wheel :)

if you worry about overhead, what is your definition for overhead? is it the file-size (binaries are about 0,5mb) or the overhead in the logic.
well for the logic-part: i think that implementing their `IJob`-interface does a good job to force better code of the consumer. i'm not that big friend of inline-methods (just as an example, as you might fire their pointers on timer elapse) - classes would give you much more possibilities, and once again, force better oop, domain-design, ...

but: doing `Console.WriteLine(...)` with quartz.net would be overkill ... :)

Comment: does it add much overhead to a small WPF app Andreas? i.e. above & beyond the approach Mikael gave?  (i.e. to what extent would it be using a sledgehammer to crack a nut so to speak here?)

Comment: +1 Didn't know about this library, but I will certainly keep it in mind.

Answer (score 16):

I'm assuming you have tried something already, and that it drifts.

If you want something to fire at say every 5 seconds from the hour (5,10,15,20..), you could set your timer to fire once, then in your callback, reset the timer to fire at DateTime.Now + number of seconds to the next 5 second interval.

This would prevent any drifting as long as your clock is correct.

Something like this

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new Timer();

void Init()
{
    timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    int wait = 5 - (DateTime.Now.Second % 5);
    timer.Interval = wait*1000;
    timer.Start();
}


void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    int wait = DateTime.Now.Second % 5;
    timer.Interval = wait * 1000;
    timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: sounds good - I guess I was wondering if there wasn't already a function that would do this already buried in the .NET framework somewhere